# Spring Kafka JDBC Connector compatibility

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Is Kafka JDBC connect compatible with `Spring-Kafka` library?

I did follow https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/ and still have some confusions.

Comment: What are your confusions?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to consume from a Kafka topic and write to a JDBC database. Some of your options are

- Use plain Kafka consumer to consume from the topic and use  Jdbc api to write the consumed record to database.
- Use spring Kafka to consume from the Kafka Topic and spring  jdbc template or spring data to write it to the database
- Use Kafka connect with Jdbc connector as sink to read from topic and write to a table.

So as you can see

- Kafka Jdbc connector is a specialised component that can only do one job.
- Kafka Consumer is very genric component which can do lot of job and you will be writing lot of code. In facr, it will be the foundational API from which other frameworks build on and specialise.
- Spring Kafka simplfies it and let you deal with kafka records as java objects but doesnt tell you how to write that object to your db.

So they are alternative solutions to fulfil the task. Having said that you may have a flow where different segments are controlled by different teams and for each segment, any of them can be used and Kafka topic will act as joining channel

Comment: Thanks Kavith. My ultimate aim is to a. read from topic b. persist on db c. retrieve from db using time interval and again sending to another topic. This is of course going to be an atomic transaction. Could you please suggest ? Thanks.

Comment: It is a separate issue and someone else may have better answer so raise separate question. I didn't come across a use case like that. I have used 1) reading from db writing it topic and 2) reading from that topic and writing it to another db. But in your use case, db is in the middle, I don't understand it